# Symfony serializes dates as empty arrays

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm making a JSON REST API using Symfony 5.2. One of the API calls returns a date, however I noticed the date is always serialized as an empty array (`[]`). Here is an extract from the response I get:

```json
{"count":1,"data":[{"id": 6, "published_from":[],"published_until":[]}]}
```

The other fields like `id` are correct, but the dates aren't. In the database, the fields are populated with dates.

I tried running the query with the default `services.yaml` with the same result.

Here is the field declaration in the entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups({"base", "updatable"})
     */
    private $publishedFrom;
```

Finally, still edited for brevety, here is relevant business logic code (eg: in Controller):

```php
           $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->andWhere('p.store = :store')
                ->setParameter('store', $store_id);
        $paginator = new Paginator($qb, false);
        $entity = ['count' => count($paginator), 'data' => $paginator);
        return $this->json($entity, context: ['groups' => ['base']]);
```

It looks like the `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer` isn't used by default, when I think it should be.

I'm fairly sure it's only a matter of configuration, but I can't find any clue.

After some debugging, I've seen that both dates are replaced by empty arrays at line 203 of `AbstractObjectNormalizer`:

```php
$data = $this->updateData($data, $attribute, $this->serializer->normalize($attributeValue, $format, $this->createChildContext($context, $attribute, $format)), $class, $format, $context);
```

Thank you for any input.

EDIT: See my answer for more information on this bug.

Comment: Does this help you? https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#using-callbacks-to-serialize-properties-with-object-instances

Comment: When you use the serializer provided by Symfony's FrameworkBundle then it should have a DateTimeNormalizer. Are you building your own serializer? Can you maybe `dump($this->serializer)` and show us the list of registered normalizers?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the answer. Even after reusing the default `services.yaml` and running `bin/console c:c`, my custom Denormalizer was still loaded somehow. It does not override the `supportsNormalization` method. In the `AbstractNormalizer` stub, this resolves to true.

The solution for me was to override it: In my denormalizers I added this to prevent them from being used for normalization:

```php
    public function supportsNormalization($data, string $format = null)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

I'll leave this issue up in case anyone encounters this very specific issue.

EDIT: I realized after re-enabling my services.yaml, that the snake_case converter re-enables this bug. I guess this is for the same reason. I have not found a workaround yet.

Github issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40818

Answer (score 0):

The problem also can be with normalizer's order(priority).
You can set it with:

```
    #services.yaml
    get_set_method_normalizer:
        class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer
            tags:
                - { name: serializer.normalizer, priority: -991 }
```

And check it:

```
 php bin/console debug:container --tag=serializer.normalizer
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).